# Xpages Download control for Client side

Tags: xpages

Xpages for Client Side: Download Control does not have the option of opening a saved attachment , it always gives the option of saving the attachment and then reopening.Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 5):

The scheme by Mark doesn't work in XPiNC ( which I think is what Client Side meant in the question ), however, Mark has since come up with another scheme which he mentioned to me and it works.

If you use a url link to open a classic notes document ( i.e. not xpages ) with the launch property open first attachment set then the attachment will be launched immediately - it works really well.

I will write something up and put it on my blog then add a link here. If you had more than one attachment you might need to construct a temporary document with just the attachment you wanted.

Comment: Upvoted you so you can get your 50 points. Welcome to stack exchange Sean. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to let users directly open files using the standard download control, but as a workaround you could create links to the files using the (old school) syntax:

```
/<yourdb.nsf>/0/<document-unid>/$file/<filename>
```

This won't add the content-disposition header that causes the file download dialog.

Comment: This doesn't work in XPiNC but mark has come up with a different scheme which I have posted above.